# Jstree : dblclick binding parameter data is undefined

Tags: jstree

I try to use good lib [jstree](http://www.jstree.com) but i have some strange problem with `dblclick` binding.
Here is my code

```
$("#basic_html").jstree({
    themes: {
        url: "http://mywork/shinframework/shinfw/themes/redmond/css/jstree/default/style.css"
    },
    "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","hotkeys", "core"],
});

$("#basic_html").bind("dblclick.jstree", function (e, data) {
    alert(e);
    alert(data);
});
```

When this code runs and i make dblclick for some node i can see 2 alerts. The first is `object` -right, the second is `undefined` - BUT i want receive data information.

Please, if some specialist solve this problem give me right way for correct use dblclick and receive "data" information about node who is i clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,

I'm trying to use the event dblclick.jstree with the following code.

.bind("dblclick.jstree", function  (event, data) {

})

The problem is that data is undefined so how can I get a reference to
my tree object?
The code above works just fine with all other events. There I get the
data and can get a reference to the tree with data.inst.

I really need som help..

Comment: Same issue. Ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this approach . . .

```
$("#basic_html li").live("dblclick", function (data) {
   //this object is jsTree node that was double clicked
   ...
});
```

First, you usually only need to know if the *li* was clicked so monitoring the event on the li will give you everything you need.  Secondly, use *live* or *delegate* for the event binding so you can manipulate the tree without breaking the event.

Once you have the node that was double clicked (the *this* object) you can then use the built-in functions like this . . .

```
if (!jsAll.is_selected(this)) { return false; } //cancel operation if dbl-clicked node not selected
```

Where . . .

```
jsAll = $.jstree._reference("basic_html")
```

Comment: unfortunately `data` is still `null` with this approach

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#basic_html").bind("dblclick.jstree", function (event) {
    var node = $(event.target).closest("li");//that was the node you double click
});
```

that's the code you want.