# Jstree dblclick binding problem

Tags: jstree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jstree dblclick binding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043987/jstree-dblclick-binding-problem)

I'm trying to use the event dblclick.jstree with the following code.

.bind("dblclick.jstree", function  (event, data) {

})

The problem is that data is undefined so how can I get a reference to
my tree object?
The code above works just fine with all other events. There I get the
data and can get a reference to the tree with data.inst.

I really need som help..

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution on this?  I'm having the same problem..

Comment: Check out my answer on his first thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043987/jstree-dblclick-binding-problem/7354246#7354246

Comment: @Toadmyster doesn't fix it.